# Program fail - wrong connection between html and javascript?

Tags: javascript

The problem is that nothing happens when pressing the button. Problem is now solved. The thing is Javascript is case sensitive, and that made it. Stupid fail from my side.

```
        <script>
        function calculate() {
        var elev = document.getElementsByName("txt");
```

would do it? But it doesn't? What's wrong?

> ```
>                     ...
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                 </td>
>                 <td>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>                     <input type="text" name="txt" value="Insert name"><br/>
>
>                     ...
>     <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate(event)" />
>         <script>
>         function calculate() {
>         var elev = document.getElementsByName("txt");
>         for(i=0; i<elev.length; i++) {
>             elev[i].used = false;
>         }
>
>         for(j=0; j<elev.length; j++) {
>             var name1;
>             var name2;
>             var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
>             var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
>
>             if (elev[r].used) {
>                 for(a=0; elev[a].used=true; a++) {
>                     elev[a] = elev[r];
>                 }
>                 }
>             if (elev[k].used) {
>                 for(b=11; elev[b].used=true; b++) {
>                     elev[b] = elev[r];
>                     if (b===11) {
>                         b=0;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>
>             name1 = elev[r];
>             name1.used = true;
>             name2 = elev[k];
>             name2.used = true;
>             document.write(name1 + " og " + name2 );
>         }
>     }
>
>          </script>
>       </body>
>     </html>
> ```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not enough. Please explain what's wrong with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'JavaScript' is case sensitive. You assign a `Calculate` handler function to the `onclick` event.

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate(event)" />
```

But the actual function name is `calculate` (which is a different function for JS).

```
function calculate() {
```

Just fix this problem and the code should work.